# Intellij cant resolve tagsoup namespace even if maven dependency added

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, tag-soup

I had a problem with TagSoup in one of my projects: even if I added maven dependency to pom, IntelliJ 13 Ultimate would still shout that it can't resolve namespace `org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser` (pointing at "ccil" bit).
So I have created a new, empty Maven project, and added 2 dependencies to it: saxon9 and tagsoup1.2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>MavenExperiment</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenExperiment</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>tagsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
        <version>9.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

And created simple class:

```
public class MavenExperiment {

    net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl impl;
    org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser pars;
}
```

The outcome:

- both saxon and tagsoup are being downloaded to my local repo
- it builds in the terminal (`mvn clean install`)
- in IntelliJ the saxon stuff is being resolved alright
- in IntelliJ the tagsoup stuff is still throwing up on the "ccil" part of the namespace with error "cannot resolve symbol"
- won't build in IntelliJ because of the above error

Any ideas? Am I missing some kind of dependency for tagsoup (certainly can't see anything on the tagsoup website about such dependency)? Thanks.

Comment: Check in your local repo for the tagsoup jar file. If it exists, check its contents. If it has contents, check to see if the class that your compiler claims is missing is in fact missing -- if so try a different version of tagsoup.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try looking at your module dependencies and see if tagsoup is listed there.